# still a mystery . thumbdata3 file space & performance hog

Tags: storage, file-system, processes, media-scanner, thumbnails

I just don't know how to fix this issue.
I have tried almost everything and give up.
I have read other threads on what to do if there is `.thumbdata3`  file that occupies a lot of space. my file occupies almost 20 gb and I cannot afford that space waste.
I have done the following to try and circumvent but nothing works

- create an Empty file with the same name.
  that empty file will eventually increase to the same size
- stick a  `.nomedia`  file in every folder that contains an image so this file does not grow in size.
  and then I repeated the above first... the file is still created.
  there are some observations have had in that regard.
- initially the dummy file I created remains as it is. then as soon as I try and open or call in Explorer through some third party app for example there is an app that needs of photo to upload so Explorer is invoked through the app to choose the photo the phone then  completely freaked out and Will hang and forces a reboot
- why this hung state happens I open up process monitor which unlike other apps will run regardless of how hung the phone is... I find the process download manager and under that the process name is `android..process.media`
  this process strikes out as the highest `CPU` consumer. and within a matter of minutes the hounded  20 gig   .thumbdat3 file is back.
  I am rooted on an  Xperia Z3 Running Android 6.0.
  another thing that I observed -if I use any third party app that is supposed to let me `CHMOD` and `C H O W N` even though an attempt to remove write permissions. for everyone, will run without errors the file permission will remain the same they will not change. dytto experience when you use `terminal emulator` and `SU` on the prompt
  [image: Process Manager screenshot]
  I wonder

  -if I disable manual this process

  android..process.media

then what happens.

- why is it that in spite of sticking in a `..nomedia` file in each and every folder in spite of that the process will build the 20 gig file.

Comment: "create an Empty file with the same name" – well, that will just be used then. Try creating a ***directory*** with the same name, that should work if you want to get rid of the thumbs completely.

Comment: no actually `.thumbdata3` file is created within    ` .thumbnails` directory ... so creating a directory with the same name will not help. I will try creating a file by the name of the directory I don't know if that would help I have to check it out

Comment: Then create `.thumbnails/.thumbdata3` as directory. If you insist on trying with a file, at least make that read-only.

Comment: I tried to mess around with octal as an su... that is one of the questions I asked in here..... even as SU  I cannot change them

Comment: I've never tried that, but a raw idea: the reason behind that most likely is the "FUSE" system used here. Assuming we're talking about `/sdcard`: that's just a "symbolic link" pointing to a different place. Maybe you can change file permissions at the "real location". Note that can be multiple "hops", the symbolic link pointing to another symbolic link. On my device, `/sdcard` points to `/storage/self/primary` which then points to `/mnt/user/0/primary` which points to `/storage/emulated/0`. The latter then is the "real location".

Comment: well one thing that totally o overlooked my attention was the fact that all this memory is from my SD card which is formatted as `exfat`  ... that is why the octal stuff does not work. so then if I dig up the Direct Path that does not use shortcut I Would Still expect the same result octals  not working .. well for the time being I created file by that name and so far so good touch wood. the weird behaviour would begin when I would try to invoke File Explorer through any kind of third party app. example there is a app to convert media from one format to the other where you need to pick your fi

Comment: pick your file using some kind of Explorer  gui... that is the time it used to completely freak out and force a reboot in fact sometimes couple of them now after I created this file it seems stable... I tried to change the picture of a contact. sofar touch wood like I said let us see

Comment: On the command line (terminal or `adb shell`), try `fatattr +r .thumbdata3` then (to revert, `-r`). That is what's used for FAT based file systems.

Comment: thank you s. so far it seems to work with just the file created by the same name.

Comment: ok I tried to run the command on `exFat` it gives me the Message  command not implemented.

Comment: Seems to be ROM specific then (it is available on my devices running LineageOS). Was worth a try. So let's see how it works out on your end; if the issue is solved, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) with the necessary details. Fingers crossed!

Comment: yep.. so far so good.... but I have read elsewhere this thing did not work.... and with my repeated attempts to prevent that Monster from growing .... I had almost Given Up any hope..... imagine Mast be in the Google Android gene... capture people's personal data that level  and send it back to mountain view.

Comment: after I get this there is absolutely no impact on the existing thumbnails the infact start showing up faster when I invoke Explorer through an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case creating an Empty file with the same name works and this problem as since then disappeared.
so a trick is to create `thumbnails` file after you delete the folder by the same name